# Displaying posts from sub taxonomies only

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

So i have main taxonomy News:

[image]

I want to display custom fields from sub-taxonomy: by-place only.

This is my args used in wp_query but it displays all posts under the taxonomy 'News'

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => 'News',
                        ),
                    ),
        );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

while($query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php the_title(); 

wp_reset_query(); endwhile; ?>
```

As mentioned, i want to display post titles from the sub-taxonomy by-place only and not everything that belongs to 'News'.
Searched all over, didnt find any hint, would be very grateful if you care to help me, Thanks!

Also, i the subtaxonomies should be called by its name like 'by-place', not its id.

Answer (score 0):

So, after little experimenting, i found the solution if anyone needs:

Instead of:

```
'terms' => 'News'
```

Use:

```
'terms' => array('News' => 'by-place')
```

News is the category name, by-place  is the sub-category.

Thank you!